# How to find latest feedback given by each user from list of feedbacks in least order?

Tags: java, collections

Feedback looks like this:

```
    public FeedbackTable(String clusterKey, Date eventStartTime, String user, Date feedbackReceivedTime, int feedback)
    {
        this.id=clusterKey;
        this.user=user;
        this.feedback=feedback;
        this.feedbackReceivedTime=feedbackReceivedTime;
        this.eventStartTime = eventStartTime;
    }
```

I get a list of these feedbacks and I want a list of feedbacks which has only the latest feedbackReceivedTime for each user.

I can iterate through the feedback list and find unique users and then for each user iterate over the feedback list to get the latest feedback but it's not least order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way how to do it using Stream API:

```java
List<FeedbackTable> feedbacks = ...; // your list of feedbacks

List<FeedbackTable> latestUsersFeedbacks
          = feedbacks.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.user, 
                                               f -> f, 
                                              (f1, f2) -> f1.feedbackReceivedTime.after(f2.feedbackReceivedTime) ? f1 : f2))
                     .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And how do I get the last `feedbackReceivedTime` for a particular `user` - what I suspected to be the purpose of the program?

Comment: @Kaplan, just do not collect it to a list and use the map to get `FeedbackTable` identified by `user`. If you need help, please, ask your own question.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I did it this way hours ago - surely I misunderstood the intensions of P K's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to solve the problem:

```
List<FeedbackTable> rawFeedbacks;
List<FeedbackTable> newestFeedbacks = 
    rawFeedbacks
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FeedbackTable::getUser))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(a -> a.getValue().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(FeedbackTable::getFeedbackReceivedTime)).get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the FeebbackTable class, then the best is to override its equals and hashcode methods and implement `java.lang.Comparable#compareTo`. Like this,

```
public class FeedbackTable implements Comparable<FeedbackTable> {
    private final String id;
    private final String user;
    private final int feedback;
    private final Date feedbackReceivedTime;
    private final Date eventStartTime;

    public FeedbackTable(
        String clusterKey,
        Date eventStartTime,
        String user,
        Date feedbackReceivedTime,
        int feedback) {
      this.id = clusterKey;
      this.user = user;
      this.feedback = feedback;
      this.feedbackReceivedTime = feedbackReceivedTime;
      this.eventStartTime = eventStartTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      FeedbackTable that = (FeedbackTable) o;
      return id.equals(that.id) && user.equals(that.user);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(id, user);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FeedbackTable that) {
      if (this.user.equals(that.user)) {
        if (this.feedbackReceivedTime.before(that.feedbackReceivedTime)) {
          return 1;
        } else if (this.feedbackReceivedTime.after(that.eventStartTime)) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return this.user.compareTo(that.user);
    }
}
```

Later on, simply use the stream API,

```
feedbackTables.stream().sorted().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HashMap` with each user as a key and update the user's latest *feedback* (`FeedbackTable`) value accordingly:

```
public ArrayList<FeedbackTable> getLatestFeedbacksForUsers(List<FeedbackTable> feedbackTableList) {
    Map<String, FeedbackTable> latestFeedbackMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (FeedbackTable ft : feedbackTableList) {
        if (latestFeedbackMap.containsKey(ft.user)) {
            if (latestFeedbackMap.get(ft.user).feedbackReceivedTime.before(ft.feedbackReceivedTime)) {
                latestFeedbackMap.put(ft.user, ft);
            }
        } else {
            latestFeedbackMap.put(ft.user, ft);
        }
    }
    List<FeedbackTable> latestFeedbacks = new ArrayList<FeedbackTable>(latestFeedbackMap.values());
    // Sort Feedbacks in descending order
    Collections.sort(latestFeedbacks, new Comparator<FeedbackTable>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FeedbackTable f1, FeedbackTable f2) {
            return f2.feedbackReceivedTime().compareTo(f1.feedbackReceivedTime());
        }
    });
    return latestFeedbacks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*it is not 100% what You are looking for*

```
Map<String, Optional<FeedbackTable>> datesMap = tables.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy( (ft) -> ft.user, Collectors.reducing(
    (ft1, ft2) -> ft1.feedbackReceivedTime.compareTo( ft2.feedbackReceivedTime ) > 0 ? ft1 : ft2 ) ) );
```

*so You need this, to get the date for a user:*
`datesMap.get( "username" ).get().feedbackReceivedTime`
*but You don't need a* `getFeedbackReceivedTime()` *method*